# Assuming on the AIME?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Is it OK to assume on the AIME competition?
In geometry problems, could you assume that a trapezoid is isosceles or something like that? 
Could you give some examples, too?
Thanks.

Comment: I forget if the AIME is an "answer-only" or a "show work" test.  When you need not show work, you can make any assumption that does not lead to contradiction. I was irritatingly good at that - in a city team training session, I once assumed two points were the same point in a problem where the conditions did not disallow it. But you have to be careful.

Comment: The AIME is an answer-only contest, but you don't need to show the graders the work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews AIME is answer only. I think your comment is sufficient for an answer.

Comment: It's fine to assume on the AIME, though I think it tends to work more frequently on the AMC10/AMC12.

Comment: Any examples, such as the one @ThomasAndrews did with the points?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is generally a helpful and time-saving strategy for the AIME as well as the AMC 10/12. However, this will not always work, so it's important not to lose geometry skills in a generalized setting. I would also suggest trying to solve the general problem after finding the answer in a special case in order to check your work, especially as sometimes it's possible to make a mistake with a limiting diagram (such as when two points are the same as Thomas Andrews suggested.)

For example, 2009 AIME #4 was the following:

> In parallelogram $ ABCD$, point $ M$ is on $ \overline{AB}$ so that 
>   $\frac{AM}{AB}=\frac{17}{1000}$ and point $ N$ is on $ \overline{AD}$
>   so that $ \frac{AN}{AD} =\frac{17}{2009}$. Let $ P$ be the point of
>   intersection of $ \overline{AC}$ and $ \overline{MN}$. Find 
>   $\frac{AC}{AP}$.

One could solve this using area ratios or similar triangles, but a straightforward solution would be to assume that the parallelogram is a square and use coordinates.